# Is there a way in JavaScript to change Shift + Enter to just Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way that in a contentEditable when doing 'shift + enter' do the same as when you press just the 'enter' key what it does is put the content inside a div instead of just adding a br.

I try disabling the shift key, but no results :( hope you can help me

```
<div class="editableDiv" contentEditable="true"><b>Hello</b> world.</div>

div{
color: green;
}
.editableDiv{
color: salmon;
}

$('.editableDiv').on('keydown', function(event) {
if (event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
    console.log('pure enter');
} else if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.altKey) {
    console.log('triggered enter');
    $(this).trigger(jQuery.Event("keydown", {
      keyCode: 13,
      altKey: false
    }));
}
});
```

Need trigger just press 'enter' key when press 'shift + enter'

Comment: I'm confused. Is `altKey` supposed to be `shiftKey` in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

so it sounds like you want 'Shift+Enter' to do the same thing as 'Enter', correct?

If so, you might put your actions into a single, separate function, and call that in both cases. For example:

```
function MyFunctionName () {
  $('.editableDiv').trigger(jQuery.Event("keydown", {
    keyCode: 13,
    shiftKey: false
  }));
}

$('.editableDiv').on('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.key === 'Enter' && !event.shiftKey) {
    console.log('pure enter');
    MyFunctionName();
  } else if (event.key === 'Enter' && event.shiftKey) {
    console.log('triggered enter');
    MyFunctionName();
  }
}
```

Also, if you don't need to do anything different for when the user hits 'Shift+Enter' vs 'Enter' you can shorten your code to this instead:

```
function MyFunctionName () {
  $('.editableDiv').trigger(jQuery.Event("keydown", {
    keyCode: 13,
    shiftKey: false
  }));
}

$('.editableDiv').on('keydown', function(event) {
   if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    MyFunctionName();
  }
}
```

And in that case, you may not need the code in the separate function.

I edited my answer to include the better comparison operator ===. See this for more information: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Also, use key instead of keyCode, as the latter is deprecated according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have typo and altKey should be shiftKey in your question.

You can do this:

```
   $('.editableDiv').on('keydown', function(event) {
    var shiftEnter = event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey;
    var enterOnly = event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey;
      if (shiftEnter || enterOnly) {
        console.log('triggered enter');
        //Do something here
      }
      else {
        console.log("Some other key pressed");
    });
```